# Romania travel visa requirements on UK work visa

Tags: uk-visa, schengen, indian-citizens

Respected Community,

I have a query regarding my entry requirements to Romania from the United Kingdom.

I am an INDIAN passport holder living in United Kingdom on a `UK Tier 2 general work visa` (now called skilled workers visa) and I also have a UK BRP (biometric residence permit) card with me.

Can I travel to Romania based on these documents ? Or do I need to apply for Romania visa?

Edit post acceptance of the answer :

Ref : https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/#whichukvisas

[image: This website is serving possibly invalid information]

Comment: The statement contained in the image about **UK residence permit** is misleading. I have added the Romanian Foreign office text to my answer, which doesn't meantion UK residence permits at all. The UK (and Ireland, Denmark) have never issued the **Long-term resident (European Union)** type meantioned in the Romanian text.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, a UK residence permit in itself does not allow entry to Romania, Bulgaria or Croatia, or to the Schengen area itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot enter Romania soly based on a United Kingdom residence permit as an Indian citizen.

If you don't have a multi (or an unused dual) entry Schengen Visa, you will require a Romanian Visa.

---

> [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Romania](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)
> **Romanian Visa**
> **VI. Do I need a visa?**
>
> **1. YES**
> Please consult the [list of states whose citizens (annex 1)](https://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/anul_2019/2019_pdf/anexa_1_en.pdf), holders of simple passports, are required a visa upon entry on the Romanian territory.
>
> **2. NO**
> Please consult the [list of states whose citizens (annex 2)](https://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/anul_2019/2019_pdf/anexa_2_en.pdf), holders of simple passports, are not required a visa to travel to Romania.
> ...
>
> **Categories of third-state nationals also exempt from the requirement to be in possession of a Romanian short-stay visa are**:
>
> - Holders of biometric passports, nationals of the following states:
>
>   - the Republic of Moldova;
>   - the Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia;
>   - the Republic of Serbia, except for the passports issued by the Serbian Coordination Division (in Serbian: Koordinaciona uprava);
>   - the Republic of Montenegro (the non-biometric passports issued by this state are no longer valid);
>   - the Georgia
>   - the Ukraine
>
> **Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States**.
> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No 565/2014/EU, Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The limited territorial validity visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The short-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The long-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia
> - The **long-term resident's EC** residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European Union.
>
> **Attention!** The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the Schengen Member States.
> ...
>
> - <sub>text as of 2021-01-02</sub>

**Note**:
The statement made at the [Visa Traveler](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/#whichukvisas):

> **UK residence permit** should have been granted for 5 or more years

does not seemed to be confirmed by the **Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Romania** text.

The [Long-term resident (European Union)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_resident_(European_Union)) is a special residence permit type issued by some EU Member states and is **not** the same as a permanent residence permit which is often (but not always) issued after 5 years of residence.

---

**Sources**:

- [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Romania](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)

  - [list of states whose citizens (annex 1) requires a visa](https://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/anul_2019/2019_pdf/anexa_1_en.pdf) (PDF)
  - [list of states whose citizens (annex 2) don't require a visa](https://www.mae.ro/sites/default/files/file/anul_2019/2019_pdf/anexa_2_en.pdf) (PDF)
- [How to travel 35 countries VISA-FREE with a UK visa [2020 edition] - Visa Traveler](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/travel-countries-visa-free-with-uk-visa/#whichukvisas)

  - [Long-term resident (European Union) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_resident_(European_Union))

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the answer with the source of this query.